# Nodejs won't redirect to another page after POST req

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, ejs

I have an todo app. After I make a post request from UI on /todo I want to redirect me back to /todo and list me all the todo tasks. This does not happen, after I submit the task it leaves me with a blank page.

```
// POST /todo
app.post('/todo', function(req, res) {

    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'description', 'completed');

    if (!_.isBoolean(body.completed) || !_.isString(body.description) || body.description.trim().length === 0) {
        return res.status(400).send();
    }

    new Todo({
        description: body.description.trim(),
        id: todoNextId,
        completed: body.completed
    }).save(function(err, todo, count) {
        res.redirect('/todo');
    });

    todoNextId = todoNextId++;
});


// GET /todo
app.get('/todo', function(req, res) {

    Todo.find(function(err, todos, count) {
        res.render('pages/todo', {
            todos: todos
        });
    });

});
```

Ejs looks like this:

```
    <form class="form-inline" action="/todo" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" >
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="completed"> Completed
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add task</button>
    </form>

<br>

<p>Current tasks:</p>
<% todos.forEach( function( todo ){ %>
<p><%= todo.description %></p>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Is the res.redirect actually called? If yes then is res.render in app.get called?

Comment: if (err) throw err; res.redirect('/todo');

Comment: It breaks in the validation 'if' when I check if description is string and not 0 and completed is bool.